# Google Drive Api, Downloading a file using powershell

Tags: powershell, google-drive-api

I was able to download a file from the google drive api, however, it only works on text files.

How do I download other types of files?

Example: The word file downloaded but when I open it, I get

> "We're sorry, we can't open file because we found a problem with its contents"

This is the code.  Thank you.

```
function getfile($uri){
    $results = Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Method GET `
    -Uri $uri `
    -Headers @{Authorization = Get-Token} `
    -ContentType application/json

    return $results
}

$fileId = "word document id"
$fileproperties = getfile -uri "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$fileId"
$actualfile = getfile -uri "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$($fileId)?alt=media"

$actualfile | out-file c:..\Desktop\$($fileproperties.name)
```

Comment: Your `getfile` function returns json content type for all requests. which is text based. if you try to return a word document as json could be that what you get back would be corrupt. I would suggest making the content type a function parameter so you can specify the correct mime type when downloading media

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I use -OutFile, it was able to download successfully.
This works only for Word and Excel documents.

```
Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Method GET `
  -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$($file.id)?alt=media" `
  -Headers @{Authorization = Get-Token} `
  -OutFile "C:fileLocation\$($file.name)"
```